# Routing one wireless router to another wireless router with internet access on both

Tags: wireless-networking, routing

I have an Asus wireless router wired to ADSL that provide Internet access, this router have also a print server (USB printer) and a 1 Terabyte DLINK NAS wired to this router. I have also a wireless Zalip 3G router with a 3G Internet key connected. The computers and tablets around the house (4 notebooks, 3 tablets and 1 desktop computer) are wireless networked,  according to the strength of the wireless signal from one or other router, but when one computer is served by one router it can not connect to computers served by the other router. How can I resolve this? How to route one router to the other one?

Comment: What models are these routers?

Comment: Please post model and revision of your ASUS router (is it with ADSL modem integrated or there is something more?) Since it has USB port odds are high that with extra USB hub and aftermarket firmware you can attach 3G USB stick for "multiwan" and eventually an USB hard disk for SAN.

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely that the routers' stock firmware supports this sort of network configuration.  Custom firmwares such as DD-WRT may have this capability, though.  See the following links for more info:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged 
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge  (OLD VERSION)